# Join two table with two different Foreign Key for get same field

Tags: sql, oracle, join, foreign-keys

in my exercise for Oracle/Sql, i have 2 table D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI and D_ENTI:

D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI has 2 FK: FK_ENTI and FK_ENTE_PROPRIETARIO and 2 field that i want get: Denominazione and Codice_Fiscale.
D_ENTI has unique Primary Key: SEQU_ENTE.

Now i want select all record of D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI with 4 fields:

- Amm_Dich_Denom: get Denominazione  when D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI.FK_ENTI=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE;
- Amm_Dich_CF: get Codice_Fiscale when D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI.FK_ENTI=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE;
- Ente_Prop_Denom:  get Denominazione when D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI.FK_ENTE_PROPRIETARIO=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE;
- Ente_Prop_CF:  get Codice_Fiscale when D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI.FK_ENTE_PROPRIETARIO=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE;

my solution is this:

```
select 
D.FK_ENTE,
D.FK_ENTE_PROPRIETARIO,
(select D_ENTI.DESC_DENOMINAZIONE from D_ENTI where D.FK_ENTE=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE) AMM_DICH_DENOM,
(select D_ENTI.CODI_CODICE_FISCALE from D_ENTI where D.FK_ENTE=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE) AMM_DICH_CF,
(select D_ENTI.DESC_DENOMINAZIONE from D_ENTI where D.FK_ENTE_PROPRIETARIO=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE) ENTE_PROPR_DENOM,
(select D_ENTI.CODI_CODICE_FISCALE from D_ENTI where D.FK_ENTE_PROPRIETARIO=D_ENTI.SEQU_ENTE) ENTE_PROPR_CF
from 
D_REL_ENTI_FABBRICATI D
```

But there is another method more elegant and afficent?

Thanks all
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
SELECT
  d.fk_ente,
  d.fk_ente_proprietario,
  de.desc_denominazione      amm_dich_denom,
  de.codi_codice_fiscale     amm_dich_cf,
  dep.desc_denominazione     ente_propr_denom,
  dep.codi_codice_fiscale    ente_propr_cf
  FROM
  d_rel_enti_fabbricati  d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN d_enti de ON d.fk_ente = de.sequ_ente
    LEFT OUTER JOIN d_enti dep ON d.fk_ente_proprietario = dep.sequ_ente
```

If you always have values in d.fk_ente and d.fk_ente_proprietario you can replace the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `JOIN`